# VirtualBox error issue connected to ExtensionsPack - Failed to load ring-0 module 'VBoxEhciR0.r0' for device 'usb-ehci'

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxEhciR0.r0: SUP_IOCTL_LDR_OPEN failed (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Failed to load ring-0 module 'VBoxEhciR0.r0' for device 'usb-ehci' (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Comment: the original answer has been posted here by me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789314/13640429

Answer (score 1):

In my case I don't disable USB support, insted I selected an USB controller that will not include EHCI, because the main problem reported by de exception was with

```
VBoxEhciR0.r0 for device 'usb-ehci'
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to disable the USB support , at the project settings -> under the USB section. Uncheck "Enable USB"

Answer (score 0):

Other answers from the original obsolete, incorrectly placed question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719572/virtualbox-error-issue-connected-to-extensionspack-failed-to-load-ring-0-modul

=============================

In my case I don't disable USB support, insted I selected an USB controller that will not include EHCI, because the main problem reported by de exception was with

`VBoxEhciR0.r0 for device 'usb-ehci'`

answered Dec 4 '20 at 10:59 - Luis Carlos

=============================

forum archlinux : downgrade to previous extension pack (and possibly Vbox previous version)

answered Dec 4 '20 at 20:03 - Recoh23

=============================

For me, I solved this by activating USB in 1.1 instead of 2.0.

Disabling USB completely also works

answered Jan 19 at 10:07 - 936940